# mysql - add foreign key constraint to a table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have two tables name `users` , `user_friends`. user has over 10 million records and user_friends has more then 600 million records. The problem is that it does not have a constraint . i.e when a user is deleted their friends list is their in the database. it was working fine. but now we have implement a new functionality that has user_social_friends . I have applied all constraint in it.

now I want to apply constraint on the `user_friends` table like this

```
SQL query:


ALTER TABLE `user_friends` ADD  CONSTRAINT `user_id_key_contstraint` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
MySQL said: Documentation

#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`callerap_finder`.`#sql-d9fad_24e`, CONSTRAINT `user_id_key_contstraint` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

my question is that how can I apply a constraint on the user_friends table so in the table user_friends all those record delete or set to null who's user is deleted.

Comment: The data relationships must be satisfied before you can add the constraint. Adding the constraint does not delete rows or change values to NULL. You have to do that using either DELETE or UPDATE before you try to add the constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly that you have records in `user_friends` that violate the foreign key constraint you're trying to add.
you can follow these steps to avoid this error

1.First delete or set null those records in `user_friends` table.

```
DELETE FROM user_friends WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM user);
```

2.Now run your query to add constraints

```
ALTER TABLE `user_friends`
ADD CONSTRAINT `user_id_key_constraint`
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
REFERENCES `user`(`id`)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

But as you said you have very large amount of data then i think you have to make another table which takes the valid user ids from `user` table and based on this you can delete or update records in `user_friends` table.

For example

StepOne

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE valid_user_ids AS
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM user;
```

StepTwo

Create index if you don't have already on `user_id` in `user_friends` table.

```
 CREATE INDEX idx_user_id ON user_friends (user_id);
```

StepThree

Now all you have to do is delete or null the records and then add you constraints to delete you can use something like this

```
DELETE FROM user_friends
WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM valid_user_ids);
```

StepFour

Now just add constraints with above mention query in point 2.

Tip:-

You can fetch data in batches and update them accordingly for example

```
SELECT id
FROM user_friends
LIMIT ${batchSize}
OFFSET ${offset};
```

This query will return numbers of rows you have to map and get ids from rows like this `const userIDs = rows.map((row) => row.id).join(',');` after that change your `StepThree` like this

```
DELETE FROM user_friends
WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM valid_user_ids) AND id IN 
(${userIDs});
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're facing suggest that there are existing records in the user_friends table with userId's that doesn't exist in the user table. To be able to achieve what you want to do, first make sure that the valid userId's are attached to such users, or assign a null value to such users.

Here is what you can do.

1. Find invalid user_id references in user_friends

```js
// mysql 

SELECT user_friends.user_id
FROM user_friends
LEFT JOIN user ON user_friends.user_id = user.id
WHERE user.id IS NULL;
```

2. Update invalid user_id references to NULL or a valid user ID For example, setting them to NULL

```js
// mysql

UPDATE user_friends
LEFT JOIN user ON user_friends.user_id = user.id
SET user_friends.user_id = NULL
WHERE user.id IS NULL
```

3. After the clean up in the user_friends table with the values set for the userId, you should be able to add the foreign key constraint without any errors.

Comment: there are more then 1000 millions records.  it well take a lot of time .

Comment: Sorry there's no better way with this when it comes to mysql. A suggestion will be to automate this process with a script or a cron job, and always select a max number of items to perform this checks and do this operation or setting a default value for it. And ensure the script will start it's next batch selection from the beginning of the last selection.